# iOS app with tabbar and navigation controller

Tags: ios, navigation, tabbar

In the struggle of creating my first iPhone app I noticed that the examples from Apple either have a tabbar or navigation bar, but never both.

Is it possible to do this?

So I have here a tabbar with 3 buttons, how can I now add a navigation controller to my entire application?

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

UIViewController *activityViewController = [[[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *agendaViewController = [[[AgendaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AgendaViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *settingsViewController = [[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:activityViewController, agendaViewController, settingsViewController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

EDIT:

I'm really not following, so in my appdelegate I created a navigationController and used that as the rootViewController.

I then created a tabBarController and added this to my window

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

UINavigationController *mainViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
self.mainViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

self.window.rootViewController.title = @"test";

MainViewController *tabBarController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

But whenever I run, I get the error"

> Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a navigation controller, then create a tabBarController and add your navigation controller to it using

```
 //incase you have 2 navigation controllers
 tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController1, navigationController2, nil ];
```

Comment: he wants a navigationController for the entire application. so it has to be the root

Comment: if he initialized the tab bar controller as i described in th AppDelegate.m and then self.window.rootController=tabBarController; it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is quite easy in concept:

Your rootViewController has to be your navigationController, because it is pushing your views back and forth.

```
YourRootController *cont = [[YourRootController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cont];
```

Where`YourViewController` is a subclass of `UITabBarController`

That's it.